# Model relationship creation uses the wrong field in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to create a new model using the relationship between a two model `module` and `chapter` and they have `HasMany` relationship between them as follow :

```
//Module mode
public function chapters()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Chapter::class, 'module_slug', 'slug');
}

//Chapters Model
public function module()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Module::class, 'module_slug', 'slug');
}
```

And here's how I'm storing the models :

```
    $module = Module::create([
        'title' => $request->module_title,
        'icon' => $request->module_title
    ]);

    $module->chapters()->create([
        'pdf_url' => $path,
        'title' => $request->chapter_title
    ]);
```

### The Issue :

The problem I got is that the `$module->chapters()->create()` is using the `id` not the `slug` which I'm specifying as the **primary key** like this :

```
//Module model
protected $primaryKey = 'slug';
protected $keyType = 'string';


//Chapters model
protected $primaryKey = 'slug';
protected $keyType = 'string';
```

I don't know why it uses the `id` field like this screenshot :

[image: The issue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your models:

```php
public $incrementing = false;
```